# Vim doesn't expand <cfile>

Tags: vim

I'm having a problem when trying to make vim expand the file name under cursor. For example:

```
include("../path/file.php");
```

When the cursor is on file name and I type `gf` the file.php is opened just fine. However, when I remap the `gf` command in vimrc this way: `map gf :tabnew <cfile><CR>`, then instead of opening the file in a new tab `gf`  just opens up an empty file.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Change your ' marks to ` and the formatting will be fixed.

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing the formatting for you.

Comment: Is your mapping doing the same as `Ctrl-W gf`?

Comment: It appears so, I didn't know you can do it this way. Though, mapping `gf` still seems a good idea as I would always want to open in a new tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be.

```
:nnoremap gf :exe 'tabnew '.expand('<cfile>')<cr>
```

Comment: Thanks, Luc, but result is the same - blank file.

Comment: Then the current &path is likelly not "compatible" with the file name under the cursor.

Comment: Yes, that's what I finally figured out as well. I assumed that when you edit a file the current path is automatically set to the file path but obviously that's not the case. Only after I did `:cd /correct_path` manually the `gf` stared to work.

Answer (score 1):

If I have the following directory structure:

```
~
|- ./foo/
|     `-- bar.php
`- ./baz/
      `-- bang.php
```

..and in bang.php: `<?php include('../foo/bar.php'); ?>`

This mapping works fine for me: `:nnoremap gf :tabe <cfile><cr>` .  The file ~/foo/bar.php is opened in a separate tab.